# Qt program in single application mode font problem

Tags: qt, ubuntu, embedded-linux, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-jetson

I have a qt program in my jetson nano on ubuntu 18.04. I am running it in *single application mode*. I created a session and that session runs directly my qt program. But font sizes are small according to normal ubuntu session. Why this is happening? Can't qt access system fonts in single application mode?

If yes, How to make it access to fonts in my single application session?